# how mathematical operations inside computers is possible if binary numeric character codepoints value are not the same as the numeric character

Tags: character, ascii, numeric, codepoint

How if the (ascii) numeric character(0123456789) codepoints are not the same binary equivalent values of the (ascii) numeric character mathematic operations inside computer systems is done for example

the ascii value of numeric character 1 is 00110001 not 00000001 in this case how mathematical operations are possible if the binary codepoint of 1 is not 00000001

Comment: Because the representation of an Ascii numeric character, is not the same as the representation of an integer on which a mathematical operation would usually be performed.

Comment: In a (simple) nutshell: the ASCII (or Unicode) codepoint for the character `1` is translated to the chosen binary representation (often, though not always, *twos-complement*) and the computer's arithmetic is performed on that representation.  Results, similarly, are translated from internal representations to codepoints.  Beyond that, consult an *introduction to computer architecture*, you'll find gazillions on the net or in your favourite bookshop.